# AWK remove query params from URL

Tags: parsing, url, awk

I have access.log file with >1m lines. The exaple of line:

```
113.10.154.38 - - [27/May/2016:03:36:26 +0200] "POST /index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin&plugin=imgmanager&file=imgmanager&method=form&cid=20&6bc427c8a7981f4fe1f5ac65c1246b5f=cf6dd3cf1923c950586d0dd595c8e20b HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "BOT/0.1 (BOT for JCE)" "-"
```

I need to parse log lines to count 10 most common urls, BUT i need to remove query params from url. Without query params i wrote this code

```
awk '{print $7}' test.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | \
head | awk '{print NR,"\b. URL:", $2,"\n   Requests:", $1}'
```

But i don't know how to remove query params and count top 10 most common urls without params to get clear top of requests.

Comment: Have you looked at the bash parameter expansion operators? There's one specifically for removing the end of a string that matches a pattern.

Comment: Look here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: i used this one `awk '{print NR,"\b. URL:", ${2%%\?*},"\n   Requests:", $1}'` but i get syntax error `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
`

Comment: You're trying to use bash syntax in an awk script.

Comment: but i cant print nr in echo, only in awk

Comment: You asked how to do it in bash, not how to do it in awk.

Comment: In `awk` use the `sub()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sub()` function to remove a pattern from a string.

You also need to do this when you're extracting the field to sort and count unique values.

```
awk '{sub(/\?.*/, "", $7); print $7}' test.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | ...
```

Comment: That literally doesn't work at all. I get full URL with all parametrs

Comment: even if i do `cat test.log | awk '{sub(/\?.*/, $7); print $7}'` or your line, i get this -
`/index.php/index.php?option=com_jce?option=com_jce&task=plugin&plugin=imgmanager&file=imgmanager&method=form&cid=20&6bc427c8a7981f4fe1f5ac65c1246b5f=cf6dd3cf1923c950586d0dd595c8e20b
`

Comment: Fixed it, I was missing an argument to `sub()`. I've tested this and it works.